# $\vec A×\vec B×\vec C$ cross product rule of three vectors

Tags: vectors, cross-product

I try to find notation of cross product rule of three vectors and I found:

$$\vec A×(\vec B×\vec C) = \vec B(\vec A.\vec C) - \vec C(\vec A.\vec B)$$

Is this notation correct for $\vec A×\vec B×\vec C$ ?

Comment: The vector product is non-associative, so writing $A\times B\times C$ is a sin.

Comment: The problem is that "AxBxC" is not well defined because the cross product is not "associative".  Ax(BxC) is not the same as (AxB)xD

Comment: Similarly, the dot product is only defined between two vectors, so writing $A \cdot B \cdot C$ is a cosin

Comment: @Sun It's hard to understand the source of your confusion.  What do you mean by $A \times B \times C$? What (to the best of your understanding) is the difference between $A \times B \times C$ and $A \times (B \times C)$?

Comment: The question is write the cross product of three vectors V= A×B×C?But I do not find formula this

Comment: @Sun What do you mean by "the question is"? Is this a question that you have come across in a textbook or in your class? Or, is this a question that you have made on your own? If this is a question that you created, then **you** have to tell us what $A \times B \times C$ means.

Comment: @sai-kartik By inserting parentheses, you have edited out what seems to be the entire point of this question. Please be more careful in the future.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I simply placed the parentheses according to what the OP has written in the formula.. but of course i will be careful in the future

Comment: This question is a question I have seen in the book. Let me try to explain it better. Let us have vectors A, B and C.Can we multiply these three vectors with cross product at the same time?

Comment: @Sun you can but the order of multiplication is important

Comment: @Sun As the first comment on this question indicates, the expression $A \times B \times C$ (without parentheses) has no standard interpretation. In order for the expression to be valid, you must write either $(A \times B) \times C$ or $A \times (B \times C)$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Thank you so much.Well, is the equality I wrote above correct?

Comment: @Sun Yes, the equation is correct. For more information, see [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product).